# I want to download google camera app source code on my PC using Git

Tags: android, git, github

I am new to git and I am trying to download following code :

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git

Now, I have git downloaded on my system and I have done git init. Normally, all the examples online are using GitHub. How can I pull this to my local using Git?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have git installed, then do this:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera
```